# Ansible populate dictionary values from separate file

Tags: dictionary, ansible, aws-cloudformation

I want to use Ansible CloudFormation module to deploy a Stack of infrastructure on AWS. So, I use this [Ansible CloudFormation example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/cloudformation.yaml) to work with.

In the example to pass parameters to the AWS template there is a portion like

```
args:
  template_parameters:
    KeyName: jmartin
    DiskType: ephemeral
    InstanceType: m1.small
    ClusterSize: 3
register: stack
```

Here `template_parameters` is a dictionary with key and values. Like

```
"template_parameters": {
                "DiskType": "ephemeral", 
                "ClusterSize": "3", 
                "InstanceType": "m1.small", 
                "KeyName": "jmartin"
            }
```

So, now I want to populate the dictionary values from another file where I create a plain list of the key and values. Like

```
args:
  template_parameters:
    - include: param_values.yml
register: stack
```

And in the `param_values.yml` will be like this:

```
KeyName: jmartin
DiskType: ephemeral
InstanceType: m1.small
ClusterSize: 3
```

But this is not loading the values from the file. Instead it is including the as a list.

```
"template_parameters": [
                {
                    "include": "param_values.yml"
                }
            ]
```

Which eventually returns this error:

> "msg": "argument template_parameters is of type  and we
>   were unable to convert to dict"

**Is there a way just to load the contents of the file instead of including it as the dictionary values?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the include_vars module in ansible.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html

From the docs ->

```
Loads variables from a YAML/JSON files dynamically from within a file or from a directory recursively during task runtime.
```